# Interview - filesystem design

Tags: c++, filesystems

I was asked during the interview to design a filesystem to allow users to add their own attributes to the files and folders. I just said to add the attributes to file descriptor and allow the search for a file be allowded based on this attribute criteria as well as add this attribute to be shown in file/folder details.
Looks like interviewer was not happy to much with this answer. Any advises how to answer that better?

Comment: I'd charge a consulting fee for that interview.

Comment: The question was off-topic unless it was a systems programming position, and I don't know when I last saw one of those. But you didn't answer it well. 'Add the attributes to the file descriptor' is meaningless, or circular.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suspect that the problem is that you said 'attach to a file descriptor', but a file descriptor is a transient property of a process rather than a permanent attribute of a file.  You might well provide a system call to attach an attribute to the file associated with a file descriptor, just as you would also provide one that works with a file name, but the attributes would have to be stored somewhere other than 'the file descriptor'; they'd have to be stored on disk.  If you did not make this clear, the interviewer may have misunderstood what you meant.